# Load more then 6 videos in html5 / javascript. 6 http requests limit problem?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have a standard html 5 frontend, javascript backend setup.
I need to play 8 videos synchronically.
Only 6 videos load, the last two just won't.
I heard there is a 6-http-requests-per-domain limit.
Could that be the reason? They are all in the same domain.
How would I get the videos to run at the same time in a browser?

Comment: Can you share an example of the page or a mock up?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the problem was the 6-http-requests-per-domain limit of http/1.
We switched the videos to a http/2 domain and now they all load at the same time.